# Amazon SNS developing don't send sms

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using a script to send with Amazon SNS some text messages through their API in PHP. The problem which I am trying to solve is how I can test my script without sending everytime the text message. Is there a possibility to enter a kind of 'developing key' whichs give me a full send report in PHP without sending the text message to my mobile phone? I previous used Messagebird and there is this possible.

Thank you.

```html
require './vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'ABCKEY123',
        'secret' => 'ABCSECRET123',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
);
$sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

$args = array(
    "SenderID" => "NAME",
    "SMSType" => "Transactional",
    "Message" => "Message",
    "PhoneNumber" => "+31612345678"
);

$result = $sns->publish($args);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Side-note: Are you running this code on an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, you should not put Access Key/Secret Key in the code. Simply assigned an IAM Role to the instance and it will automatically receive credentials. See: [Credentials for the AWS SDK for PHP version 3 - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to modify your code to *NOT* send to Amazon SNS, or you could have it send to an **Amazon SNS topic** that simply sends the message as an email.